# Find the coordinate of missing point in parallelogram

Tags: geometry

> PQRS is a parallelogram with vertices P(2, 3, -1), Q (6, 5, -4), R(7,
>   4, 1).  Find the coordinates of s.

My answer was (11, 6, 2) using the ratio of change between P and Q but the answer is (3, 2, 4).

I don't understand where this answer has comes from.

Comment: Did you draw a picture? You appear to have found S in the parallelogram PQSR, not PQRS. The vertices must be labelled in cyclis order.

Comment: I did draw a picture, R was below P.  I take it this is wrong?

Comment: S is opposite Q and R is opposite P

Answer (score 1):

The midpoint of $PR$ must be the midpoint of $QS$. That midpoint is 
$$
M = (4.5, 3.5, 0)
$$
From $Q$ to $M$ is the vector
$$
v = M - Q = (-1.5, -1.5, 4)
$$
Add this to $M$ to get $S$:
$$
S = M + v = (4.5, 3.5, 0) + (-1.5, -1.5, 4) = (3, 2, 4).
$$

Comment: why are we taking the midpoint?

Comment: Because in a parallelogram, the midpoints of diagonally opposite corners are the same, so that in $ABCD$, the midpoint of the segment $AC$ is the same as the midpoint of the segment $BD$ --- that's one of the first theorems we proved about them back when I took geometry, and dinosaurs roamed the earth.